# Port Prototype style JS object to use within React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have some old code in the form:

```
function Blah() {
    this.stuff = [];
    this.more_stuff = [];
    this.some_boolean = false;
    this.some_count = 0;
}

Blah.prototype.addStuff = function(something) {
    this.stuff.push(something);
}

...
```

I started a new project with React (0.14.x) and ECMAScript6. What would be the best approach to be able to re-use that old code? Do I convert the old code into a React Component? Getting my feet wet with React, any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The object interacts with another library (paperjs) to keep state and handle events for paperjs objects in a `<canvas>` element. Rather than "port/rewrite" that old code, could I just have that code in a separate file which gets bundled with everything else using webpack? I'm not sure how to instantiate that custom object within a React Component for example.

Comment: I think your question is too general because you're not explaining what that `Blah` object is used for? React components are for view specific stuff, there are any number of ways of handling model data.

Comment: I suppose the more appropriate question here is: I'd like leave the old code alone but use it within my new React set-up. So I guess this is more of a webpack/es6 import custom module question?